# Is there a way to "allow" a perl RegEx to ignore 1 character at a time when trying to match?

Tags: regex, perl, match

Basically, I have several files, each one with several lines of text, and I'm interested in finding a specific sequence of 7 letters and count how many time they appear per file using some basic regular expressions on Perl(v5.24.1).

So far no problem, but the "tricky" part is that if one of those seven letters doesn't match my pattern, I would like to count it as well (as long as it's just one).

Patterns I'm looking for: 
`'CCCAGGT', 'CCCAGTT', 'CCCAGCT', and 'CCCAGAT'.`

Examples of non-matching text that I would like to count:

```
line1 - AGGCTCAGGAG'CCCATGT'GGGCGGACCCAT --> Count as 'CCCAGGT'
line2 - CGGCTCAGGAG'CCCGGGT'GGGCGGTCCCAT --> Count as 'CCCAGGT'
```

I'm including a piece code (at the bottom) to further explain what I'm searching and what I've thought so far, but it has to be a better way of doing this.

So, do you know if it's possible to "tell" Perl that I can tolerate 1 mismatch in the sequence when using the `=~ m/` operator? OR another function to use?

Thanks a lot for your help!

```perl
  if ($elements[0] =~ m/CCCAGGT/){
    $mutg = $mutg + $elements[1];
  }
  elsif ($elements[0] =~ m/CCCAGTT/){
    $mutt = $mutt + $elements[1];
  }
  elsif ($elements[0] =~ m/CCCAGAT/){
    $muta = $muta + $elements[1];
  }
  elsif ($elements[0] =~ m/CCCAGCT/){
    $mutc = $mutc + $elements[1];
  }
  else {
    if ($elements[0] =~ m/.CCAGGT/){
      $mutg = $mutg + $elements[1];
    }
    elsif ($elements[0] =~ m/.CCAGTT/){
    $mutt = $mutt + $elements[1];
    }
    elsif ($elements[0] =~ m/.CCAGAT/){
      $muta = $muta + $elements[1];
    }
    elsif ($elements[0] =~ m/.CCAGCT/){
      $mutc = $mutc + $elements[1];
    }
    else {
      [[AGAIN BUT WITH THE "." IN THE SECOND POSITION AND SO ON]]
    }                         
  }
```

Comment: Does this do what you want? `/.CCAGGT|C.CAGGT|CC.AGGT|CCC.GGT|CCCA.GT|CCCAG.T|CCCAGG./` It's hideous, but if it works, it's a start.

Comment: Tip: There's no point in searching for `CCCAGGT` then for `.CCAGGT` if you don't care which one matched

Comment: @ikegami I'm still trying to decide whether to count all of them nonetheless, or count all of them but indicating how many of them had an "accepted" mismatch. Thanks tho!

Comment: Are you also interested in capturing small insertions/deletions or only substitutions?

Comment: @AndreaT. For the moment indels are managed differently so is out of the equation in this problem. I have solved the problem using ikegami's (and sort of Diab Jerius') answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simply check if there's a match (as opposed to finding the nearest match), we could build the patterns (`.CCAGGT`, `C.CAGGT`, etc) dynamically.

```
my $target_seq = "CCCAGGT";

my @parts = map quotemeta, split //, $target_seq;
my $fuzzy_pat =
   join "|",
      map { join("", @parts[0..$_-1], ".", @parts[$_+1..$#parts]) }
         0..$#parts;

my $fuzzy_re = qr/$fuzzy_pat/;
```

This can be extended to check for multiple sequences at once, as long as one doesn't care which sequence is found.

```
use List::Util qw( uniq );

my @target_seqs = qw( CCCAGGT CCCAGTT CCCAGAT CCCAGCT );

my @fuzzy_pats;
for my $pat (@target_seqs) {
   my @parts = map quotemeta, split //, $pat;
   for my $i (0..$#parts) {
      push @fuzzy_pats, join("", @parts[0..$i-1], ".", @parts[$i+1..$#parts]);
   }
}

my $fuzzy_pat = join "|", sort uniq @fuzzy_pats;
my $fuzzy_re = qr/$fuzzy_pat/;

$mtg += $elements[1] if $elements[0] =~ $fuzzy_re;
```

Answer (score 4):

It may be possible with regex but it will be overly complicated, regex is not designed for fuzzy matching. You may consider [Text::Fuzzy](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Fuzzy). The normal interface would require first somehow turning your lines into possible sequences to consider.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Fuzzy;
my $fuzzy = Text::Fuzzy->new('CCCAGGT', max => 1);
my @matches = $fuzzy->nearestv(\@possible);
```

The fuzzy_index function may also be useful for searching a larger text string similar to regex, but only returns the closest match within the string.

Comment: [Doesn't work for me](https://pastebin.com/XM6pwdYD). There's also the issue that even if it did work, it wouldn't be efficient at search for multiple sequences in multiple strings as the OP wants

Comment: @ikegami The object interface doesn't search strings. Hence the requirement of first finding the substrings to match against. How or whether that's doable would require more information (at least for me).

Comment: Well, I suppose you could find every substring of the right length L. There would be N+L-1 of them. This would probably make the solution O(N^2) instead of O(N), so it's a poor choice for the problem at hand